# vba delete column if there is only one kind of value present

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, repeat, vba

I need to write a code that will delete an entire column if all the values in that column are the same or blank.

In the example below I would need to erase column "Amount". 
What would be the VBA code to do this?

[image: example]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOXEl.png                                Here is the link to the example image

Comment: Could you post your attempted code so we don't waste time by duplicating your work so far? If you have yet to attempt anything, do some research ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/vba-excel) is a good source), and attempt this yourself. You can edit your question to include your attempted code if you run into a more specific problem after that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, here's one way of doing it.

```
Sub deleteColumn()
  Dim r As Range, c As Range, Col As Collection
  On Error GoTo errTrap
  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A15") '<<=== exclude heading, chg to suit
  Set r = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
  Set Col = New Collection
  For Each c In r
    Col.Add c.Value, CStr(c.Value)
  Next c
  Exit Sub
errTrap:
  Select Case Err
    Case 1004, 457 'all blanks, or duplicate found
      r.EntireColumn.Delete
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If this was helpful please check as answered.  Thanks.